# Upgrading sharepoint 2007 to 2013

Tags: migration, upgrade, feature-upgrade

We have a sharepoint 2007 site with some custom coding as a solution and web parts, now I want to upgrade that site to sharepoint 2013.
I have read about Avepoint tool, which migration tools do you suggest?

Comment: Keep in mind that DocAve (AvePoint's product) is simply a migration tool - it will copy your CONTENT from SiteA to SiteB. It will automatically create sub-sites as needed during the copy, and can copy permissions as well. However, when we tried to use it there were numerous issues with custom web parts and code. It's really only something I'd recommend if you're doing a straight copy/migration of a vanilla SharePoint site.

Comment: If your sites have a lot of customizations, you're probably better off just biting the bullet and upgrading a copy of each content database to 2010, then 2013 from there. Currently I'm not aware of a way to jump straight from 2007 to 2013 directly.

Comment: you mean copy/migration sharepoint content db is a better solution when I have a lot of customize web parts and solutions? should I do anything with visual studio after migration?

Comment: Individual solutions will need to be loaded into VS and updated to the appropriate version of SharePoint - the DLL files are all different version numbers than what 2007 had. Both 2010 and 2013 have a pre-upgrade checker utility that should point out any trouble spots before the actual upgrade process.

Comment: This is the process I'm referring to - http://www.winwire.com/moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2013-migration-using-database-attach-method/

Answer (score 0):

I am sure no 3rd party tool supporting the custom solution migration. 3rd party tools help to directly move the content from 2007 to 2013(almost all OOTB stuff).

Now you have two options.

**Option # 1**

- Re do your custom code in Visual studio and compile it as per the 2013.
- Use the tool to move the content

**Option # 2** (Dont use the 3rd party tool)

- You need a interim SharePoint 2010 environment
- Now migrate the content DB from 2007 to 2010 to 2013
- Deploy your re complied code.

Some good articles. [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0421d4f9-8626-403e-b462-962f4bd51908/migration-from-sharepoint-2007-to-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral)  another [Link](https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/mark-jones/2013/01/07/upgrading-a-custom-application-to-sharepoint-2013#.VRVqv_nF9MM)

.